# How to apply word2vec to dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gensim, word2vec

I have to apply word2vec on one of the feature of my dataframe and re-add this processed feature to my original dataset.

```
df[col] :
1                                 index.html
2                                 index.html
3                                 index.html
4         deliver?section=Delivery%10Details
5                                   shipment
                         ...                
204226                   home?section=To
204227                   home?section=To
```

I have tokenized the column using below command

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
df['col_token'] = df['col'].apply(word_tokenize)

df['col_token']:
1                                    [index.html]
2                                    [index.html]
3                                    [index.html]
4    [delivery, ?, section=Delivery, %, 20Details]
5                                      [shipment]
Name: col_token, dtype: object
```

and then I am appling word2vec model on the same using below code however, I get an error : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

```
model_word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
seed=123,
min_count=1,
window=2,
workers=4)

df['new_col'] = model_word2vec.wv[df['col_token']]
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`word2vec.wv[...]` expects to be called on a single string word, but you're calling it on `df['col_token']`, which is a pandas Series. But word2vec doesn't know anything about pandas, and the function call isn't vectorized (in the pandas sense).

So you want to do:

```
df['col_token'].apply(word2vec.wv)
```

Comment: I still get this error after using suggested command `TypeError: 'KeyedVectors' object is not callable`

Comment: What is the dtype of the column `df['col_token']`? What is the type of the element `df['col_token'] [0]`?

Comment: dtype of `df['col_token']` is `pandas.core.series.Series` and `df['col_token'] [0]` gives `KeyError: 0` as the index is starting from 1.

Comment: No not the type of `df['col_token']`, the **dtype**. (Obviously its type must be Series, it's a column of a dataframe). But look at `df.info()` or `df.dtypes` to get its dtype.

Comment: it is an object type

Comment: And tell us the type of `df['col_token'] [1]`, or any element.

Comment: numpy.dtype[object_]

Comment: ... 'object' is just a pandas placeholder for a Python list/string/object... look inside `df['col_token'] [1]`. Print it. Whatever you need to do find its actual underlying type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242836/discussion-between-be-real-and-smci).